# Table myapp_tableName already exists

Tags: django

i have created a django app and add some model fields on models.py

1.logo

2.shirt

and their attributes are 
pid, name and org
then i added a new attribute price to them. and execute command python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate i got the error 'Table buapp_dealer already exists.

here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class founder(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.EmailField(null=True)
    headshot=models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    __repr__=__str__

class supporter(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email=models.EmailField(null=True)
    headshot=models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    __repr__=__str__

    class Admin:
        list_display=('name','address','email')


class dealer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    #city=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website=models.URLField(null=True)
    rep=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    __repr__=__str__

    class Admin:
        list_display=('name','address','country')
        list_filter=('name','country')
        ordering=('rep',)
        search_fields=('name')

class tshirt(models.Model):
    price=models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='default')
    fontimage=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/tshirts',null=True)
    backimage=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/tshirts',null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pid)
    __repr__=__str__
    class Admin:
        list_display=('pid','price','fontimage')
        list_filter=('price')
        ordering=('-pid')
        search_fields=('name')



class logo(models.Model):
    pid=models.IntegerField()
    price=models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    org=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/tshirts',null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pid)
    __repr__=__str__
    class Admin:
        list_display=('pid','price','img')
        list_filter=('price')
        ordering=('-pid')
        search_fields=('org')

class final(models.Model):
    pid=models.IntegerField()
    price=models.FloatField(default=0.00)
    fontimg=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/finals',null=True)
    backimg=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/finals',null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pid)
    __repr__=__str__
```

Comment: What's the output of `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Have you tried excuting `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: try to post the model code, the latest one and also post your traceback

Comment: @Kye python manage.py migrate command raises error Table buapp_dealer already exists

Answer (score 0):

Check if the field you added (price) is actually in the database then **make a backup** of your database and try running this (for appname buapp_dealer)

```
python manage.py migrate --fake buapp_dealer
```

This will mark migrations as complete.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate --fake buapp_dealer

python manage.py migrate
```

It should solve your problem